# How to store custom version / differentiell branches in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

We want to create custom versions of our software for different customers. These custom version can be more or less customized so there might be 10 changed files for smaller ones and hundreds of changed files for bigger ones. ***Since there might be a big number of custom version, be don't want to copy/branch the whole project, but rather only add changed files to the custom version folder.*** The structure might look like this:

```
standard version:
- foo
  - bar
    - Class1
    - Class2
    - Class3

custom version x:
- foo
  - bar
    - Class1

custom version y:
- foo
  - bar
    - Class2
    - CustomClassY
```

When building the project, we would checkout the standard version first and the custom version second, overwriting standard files with the customized. Then compile, install, test and so on.

My question is: is this a useable concept? Have somebody deployed this? What are the obstacles? And what are the alternatives?

One alternative that comes to mind is creating a traditional branch, but merge changes from the standard version regularly. Maybe this could be automated so the build server would merge changes every night before doing a full build?

Comment: I think your approach with the "traditional branch" would work. But keep in mind, that changes in `Class1` of the standard version would also mess up the `Class1` in the custom version x. 

But anyway: what should happen if `Class1` of the standard version is modified? Should the custom versions become updated, too? So probably a conflict during a merge is useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but there are caveats - you will need to consider how you will handle (for example), deleting a file that is in the base version in the custom folder.

Another approach is to have a bunch of customer specific directories (under /customer). Treat the 'vanilla' version as a customer with no deltas. Then your build process is to take the base version and iterate over the customer directories, building each in turn. For bonus points, you could look at using a union filesystem (like aufs) so that you don't have refresh the base code each time.

Or, you could keep each customer's changes as patch files. This will require slightly more work on checkin/out (unless you script it with hooks), but should make the process of keeping the customer files up to date much easier.

Comment: Why would you do this - the first uses a lot of space and complexity and the second is what SVN branches does for you __automatically__.

Comment: The first only uses enough space to hold the new versions of the files.
The second removes the need for automatic rebasing as the underlying code changes.

Comment: SVN only stores the deltas on a branch anyway. SVN does the second for you - if you create a branch with no changes it stores the fact and the version information - only!  As you make changes on branches it actually stores patches or deltas only.  BUT rather than in your case, checking out your trunk and then applying patches then resolving conflicts each time you would like a build SVN will let you merge in changes from the trunk, resolve the conflicts and then commit that as a new version of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

**Do** use branches it is part of what they are there for.

The important thing to remember is that providing you check out `your_repository/trunk` then use  either:

```
svn copy
```

or if you are using a client such as TortoiseSVN us the branch/tag option.

And create `your_repository/branches/customer_name`.

Then it creates what is called a ***shallow copy*** - which basically just records `your_repository/branches/customer_name = your_repository/trunk@SVN_Rev_number_at_the_time` *which takes up next to **no** space in the repository* - from then on only the branch specific changes take any space and you can merge change from the trunk into the branch very quickly as you will only ever need to do any work on resolving conflicts in the files that have changed on **both** trunk and that branch.

**But** don't let whoever is creating the branches check out `your_repository`, use *file explorer* or some such to copy from `trunk` to `branches/some_name` and then **add** it to the repository - don't laugh I have had one developer do this multiple times even after he has been shown the mess it makes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that SVN branches don't take up much space, yes. However, I don't worry about space that much, but I worry about the two versions drift away from each other and fixes have to be done twice. When we only add changed files to the branch, we can all fixes and one has to explicitly decide to fork a particular class and may think about it twice. Maybe one would then refactor the class and only fork and overwrite portions of it. Secondly, I'm really worried about automated merges. Will there be a lot of stupid conflicts and/or tree conflicts every other day?

Comment: @TimBüthe - The merges only happen when you trigger them and you are less likely to get drift when you have a single tool that stores all of your variants and provides tools for migrating changes between them.  Any changes that do not affect your 'customised' bits will be automatically ported on a merge so the number of stupid conflicts depends largely on well structured code - if all the bits that customers are likely to need changed are in one area and the common stuff in another then this would be minimised.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I haven't had the need for such a requirement, what about avoiding branches entirely and just storing the differences for each customer version as a [patch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html) file?

You should then be able to incorporate application of each diff into your build/release process. For example, if you have a `CustomerPatches` directory, containing one patch file for each customer, you could iterate over each patch file to create a separate release.

[MrD's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613697/how-to-store-custom-version-differentiell-branches-in-svn/18651056#comment27428482_18613697) comment to your question is also valid, and any errors generated from the application of a patch file indicate a problem that should fail the build.

Obviously in the longer term, consider refactoring your application to avoid such a predicament :)